# Not able to update my sqlite table

Tags: android

```
public void entry(int pos){
    String str = String.valueOf(pos);
    String s = String.valueOf(1);
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_BOOKMARK, s);
    myDataBase.update(DB_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + str, null);
}
```

I am using the above code to update my table, but getting errors..

Comment: and what is your error LogCat please

Comment: 06-23 14:13:29.821: I/Database(311): sqlite returned: error code = 8, msg = prepared statement aborts at 21: [UPDATE dowry2 SET contents=? WHERE _id = ?]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should `update`

```
myDataBase.update(DB_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(str) });
```

Comment: 06-23 14:13:29.821: I/Database(311): sqlite returned: error code = 8, msg = prepared statement aborts at 21: [UPDATE dowry2 SET contents=? WHERE _id = ?] this is the error m getting

Comment: is your str value null? confirm that and Database is not closed in state

Comment: I myself found out the problem. it was solved using,  SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();